# How do I use the input-append classes for Simple Form Bootstrap gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I think I'm missing it. [The example application](http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/) for [simple_form-bootstrap](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap) never showed how to use `input-append`. I tried a couple of other ways but they didn't work.

```
<div class="controls">
 <div class="input-append">
  <input type="text" size="16" id="appendedInput" class="span2">
   <span class="add-on">.00</span>
 </div>
   <span class="help-inline">Here's more help text</span>
</div>
```

I need this so the error messages used with Bootstrap show up and I'm able to design my forms a certain way. How would I use the `add-on` and `help-inline` on a [horizontal form](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, Simple form bootstrap does support it. I should have looked at `append` just like `prepend`. For example:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@article, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, :wrapper => :append, :class => "inline" do %>
   <%= f.input_field :name %>
    <%= content_tag :span, "?", :class => "add-on abbn" %>
   <% end %>
   <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```